# Extracting result of aggregation in elasticsearch using java API

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

Hi new bee to elasticsearch, I am getting inputs dynamically and using sub aggregation to get dynamically, hope this is correct !!

```
    List<String> bRuleCol = new ArrayList<>();

    bRuleCol.add("name");
    bRuleCol.add("id");   //this columns may dynamically grow

    String[] itemsArray = new String[bRuleCol.size()];
    itemsArray = bRuleCol.toArray(itemsArray);
    TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = null;
    for(int i=0;i<itemsArray.length;++i) {
         aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms(itemsArray[i]+"_group").field(itemsArray[i]);
         for(int j = i; j<itemsArray.length;j++) {
             aggregation.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms(itemsArray[j]+"_group").field(itemsArray[j]));  
         }

         break; 
    }
```

This is leading to below output,

```
"aggregations" : {
        "name" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "Bhounsley",
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "id" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : 1,
                    "doc_count" : 1
                  },
                  {
                    "key" : 4,
                    "doc_count" : 1
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key" : "Raju",
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "id" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : 2,
                    "doc_count" : 1
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key" : "Raghu",
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "id" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : 3,
                    "doc_count" : 1
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

I want to return above output in a good way to UI so that it can populate in grid, please let me know how to frame above output in understandable way, stuck because buckets may grow dynamically as inputs grow.

Expected output will be,

```
name       id    count
=======================
Bhounsley   1      1

Bhounsley   4      1

Raghu       2      1
```

Comment: When you say UI, what do you mean ? It' also in Java ? How does your UI communicate with your backend which interact with Elasticsearch ? And what is the problem with buckets that grow dynamically ?

Comment: Hi fmdaboville, UI is Angular they communicate using REST. when I do aggregation of multiple it is hierarchical data but I need a code in tabular form . I need a java genric code which parse this hierarchical data in to tab form.stuck in this stage !!

Comment: You can simply make a POJO containing an entry and put it in a list. Then you can send it to your frontend with REST form. And your front should parse the answer to make an array or what you want.