# Aggregation on nested field, fielddata=true on nested field attribute

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have json in this format

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"CBG",
"studDetails":{
"address":"Banglore"
}
}
```

Trying to aggregate on studDetails.address getting this error

```
Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [studDetails.address].
```

Tried below curl command to set true, but  not working.

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/student -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "studDetails.address": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: please don't put the _spring-data-elastcisearch_ tag on questions that are not related to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use fieldata:true to aggregate, it could cause performance issues.

**Fielddata can consume a lot of heap space, especially when loading high cardinality text fields. Once fielddata has been loaded into the heap, it remains there for the lifetime of the segment. Also, loading fielddata is an expensive process which can cause users to experience latency hits. This is why fielddata is disabled by default.**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Use keyword instead.

Assuming your mappings look like :

```
   "studDetails":{
         "type":"nested",
           "properties":{
               "address":{
                   "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                       "keyword": {
                         "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

Then your query should look like:

```
srb.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.nested("agg1", 
"studDetails").subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("agg2").field("studDetails.address.keyword")))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the info Assael, I want to build generic framework which accepts input   irrespective of nested how can I build this using Aggregation builder? is it possible to aggregate using just path "studDetails.address.keyword" or should I pass "AggregationBuilders.nested" inside aggregation ??

Comment: studDetails is an object,meaning it should be assign as nested type. address is a field inside studDetails and you want to apply a terms aggregation on it. in order to do so you should use Nested aggregation builder and insert address aggregation as subaggregation  ,in aggregation a keyword type is used. if you don't mention it then you will have to apply fieldata:true and it can cause performance issues. if you have any question let me know

Comment: Assael please have a look at this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947433/extracting-result-of-aggregation-in-elasticsearch-using-java-api?noredirect=1#comment104209348_58947433

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was missing fully qualified path in aggregation  api, 'student.studDetails.address'

```
 srb.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.nested("agg1", "studDetails").
                subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("agg2").field("student.studDetails.address")));
```